# I want to learn J2ME, where to start with?

Tags: java-me

I am interested in making mobile oriented applications. I have a basic knowledge of core Java.
How do I get started with [J2ME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Micro_Edition)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download Netbeans (best IDE for Java ME development IMHO)
2. Read [SUN's tutorials](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/wtoolkit/) on the subject.

Do keep in mind that in order to do proper Java ME development you need:

- Windows based workstation (neither Mac OS nor Linux work because SUN's wireless toolkit doesn't work on those platforms)
- Java language knowledge. (if you don't know Java, go learn Java first)
- A fast workstation (Netbeans and Mobile Phone emulators can be really slow on older machines)